# Nested array ng-repeat not working in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a nested loop in a html template with Angular, but the last loop from the array isn't showing up.

What might be the problem?

```
{{arduinos}}    

    <div class="db-control-panel" ng-repeat="arduino in arduinos">

      {{ arduino }}

      <div ng-repeat="tubeStatus in arduino.status">

        {{tubeStatus}}

        <div ng-repeat="tube in tubeStatus">

           {{tube}}

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**arduinos**

```
[{"arduinoID":3,"status":{"tubeStatus":[0,2,0,0]}},{"arduinoID":5,"status":{"tubeStatus":[0,0]}}]
```

**arduino**

```
{"arduinoID":3,"status":{"tubeStatus":[0,2,0,0]}}
```

**tubeStatus**

```
[0,2,0,0]
```

Why is tube not showing up?

Comment: Not a good idea to use an associative array in JavaScript with number indexes. Thats the problem.

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have duplicate items at `tubeStatus` array, use `track by $index` to avoid duplication error.

refer the below code snippet:

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.arduinos = [{
      "arduinoID": 3,
      "status": {
        "tubeStatus": [0, 2, 0, 0]
      }
    }, {
      "arduinoID": 5,
      "status": {
        "tubeStatus": [0, 0]
      }
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  {{arduinos}}
  <hr>
  <div class="db-control-panel" ng-repeat="arduino in arduinos">

    {{ arduino }}
    
    <div ng-repeat="tubeStatus in arduino.status">

      {{tubeStatus}}

      <div ng-repeat="tube in tubeStatus track by $index">

        {{tube}}

      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```